# Android studio: android plugin version 2.3.3 for Gradle produces slow code

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I upgraded my Android studio some days ago. Before that, I had Gradle version 2.14.1 and Android plugin for Gradle 2.2.3, now I have Gradle 3.3 and Android plugin 2.3.3.

My app does some image and signal processing tasks and with the version 2.3.3 my code runs very slow. For example, a simple threshold operation:

```
for (int i=0;i<480;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<640;j++)
        {
            if (randomImage[i][j] >= 191)
            {
                randomImage[i][j] = 255;
            } else {
                randomImage[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Takes 0.07 seconds with Android plugin 2.3.3 and 0.007 seconds with 2.2.3 version (10 times faster than 2.3.3 version). Now, my app requires 6.6 seconds to achieve its purpose with 2.3.3 version while with the version 2.2.3 requires 0.7 seconds. These results do not vary when I change the Gradle version, only with the plugin version.

My Android Studio version is 2.3.3 and I'm working under Ubuntu 14.10. Any clue? Am I missing something? I already did a clean build and tested on two different phones.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you run the code; on virtual device or physical device?

Comment: What version of android are those phones running on?

Comment: On a physical device with android 5.1 and 6.0.1.